# Required parameter int is not present

Tags: java, spring, spring-thymeleaf

I am working on Java Spring project, and I have this code that allows me to edit specific Quote based on it's Id.

```
//Quote's details
@GetMapping("/profile/{id}")
public String blogDetailsId(@PathVariable(value="id") long id, Model model){
    if(!quoteRepository.existsById(id)){
        return "redirect:/profile";
    }
    Optional<Quote> post = quoteRepository.findById(id);
    ArrayList<Quote> res = new ArrayList<>();
    post.ifPresent(res::add);
    model.addAttribute("post", res);
    return "detail_quote";
}


@GetMapping("/profile/{id}/edit")
public String QuoteDetails(@PathVariable(value="id") long id, Model model) {
    if(!quoteRepository.existsById(id)){
        return "redirect:/profile";
    }
    Optional<Quote> post = quoteRepository.findById(id);
    ArrayList<Quote> res = new ArrayList<>();
    post.ifPresent(res::add);
    model.addAttribute("post", res);
    return "edit_quote";
}

//Save changes into database
@PostMapping("/profile/{id}/edit")
public String QuoteEdit(@PathVariable(value="id") long id, @RequestParam String quote, @RequestParam String author, @RequestParam int votes, Model model) {
    Quote post = quoteRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(); //orElseThrow is used to throw exception when ID is not found.
    post.setAuthor(author);
    post.setQuote(quote);
    post.setVotes(votes);
    quoteRepository.save(post);
    return "redirect:/profile";
}
```

Model code:

```
@Entity
public class Quote {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;  //Generate unique ID for every quote automatically.

private String quote, author;
private int votes;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getQuote() {
    return quote;
}

public void setQuote(String quote) {
    this.quote = quote;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}

public int getVotes() {
    return votes;
}

public void setVotes(int votes) {
    this.votes = votes;
}

public Quote() {}
public Quote(String quote, String author, int votes){
    this.author = author;
    this.quote = quote;
    this.votes = votes;
}
}
```

This works as expected, and I am able to change the details of any Quote. But when I try to change specifically number of Votes by pressing **upvote** button - it results in following error:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
> Required parameter 'votes' is not present.
> org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter 'votes' for method parameter type int is not present

The code for Voting:

```
@PostMapping("/profile/{id}/upvote")
@ResponseBody
public String VoteUp(@PathVariable(value="id") long id, @RequestParam int votes, Model model) {
    Quote post = quoteRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow();
    post.setVotes(votes+1);
    quoteRepository.save(post);
    return "redirect:/profile";

}
```

The Button for Upvoting is stored inside 'detail_quote.html', which is functioning well, except for upvote button:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <title>Quote's Details</title> 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body>
  <header th:insert="blocks/header :: header"></header>
  <div class = "container mt-5">
  <div th:each="el : ${post}" class="alert alert-info mt-2">
     <h3 th:text="${el.quote}"></h3>
     <p th:text="${el.author}"></p>
     <p><b>Votes: </b><span th:text="${el.votes}"></span></p>
     <a th:href="'/profile/' + ${el.id} + '/edit'" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a><br>
     <form th:action="'/profile/' + ${el.id} + '/upvote'" method="post"><br>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit">Upvote</button><br>
     </form>
     <form th:action="'/profile/' + ${el.id} + '/downvote'" method="post">
        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit">Downvote</button>
     </form>
     <form th:action="'/profile/' + ${el.id} + '/remove'" method="post"><br>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit">Remove Quote</button><br>
     </form>
   </div>
</div>
<div th:insert="blocks/footer :: footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

So if anyone can explain to me why does it work when I change everything and does not work when I'm just trying to increase votes by 1 - I will be very thankful.

Comment: Firstly, are you sending `upvotes` in the request body ?. Secondly, why do you need `upvotes` in the request ? can't you just get the existing votes from the quote (which you are already getting it by making a db call) and increase it by 1 since you are maintaining two endpoints ?

Comment: @shanmukhavangaru I don't actually use request body. You can see it in edit_quote code. I am just sending GET and POST request to change values in DB. And it's working. However, the same thing with just votes isn't. So I don't know why and how to solve it.

Comment: Can you confirm if votes is included in the query param of the url ?

Comment: I think it does. I use it in every @RequestParam where I need the votes. As I said, it works when I update the whole instance of DB (like quote, author, and votes), but when I make only votes query param - it fails.

Comment: At html file you can see 4 buttons: Edit, Upvote, Downvote, and Remove. Edit works when I pass all parameters (quote, author, votes) and the button does what it needs to do. But the upvote takes only @RequestParam votes, because I want to change only votes.

Answer (score 1):

According to your code sample  i could not  see the args `votes` defined in your thymeleaf template as post request , but it is truely defined in backEnd Application

```
@PostMapping("/profile/{id}/upvote")
@ResponseBody
public String VoteUp(@PathVariable(value="id") long id, @RequestParam int votes, Model model) {
    Quote post = quoteRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow();
    post.setVotes(votes+1);
    quoteRepository.save(post);
    return "redirect:/profile";

}
```

so that  if you do a post request to url  `"/profile/{id}/upvote"` and have no args with `votes`  you will get error log

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400). Required parameter 'votes' is not present.
```

as suggestion  ,i  advice build the api as below sample

```
@PostMapping("/profile/{id}/upvote")
@ResponseBody
public String VoteUp(@PathVariable(value="id") long id, @RequestParam（required = false） Integer votes, Model model) {
    Quote post = quoteRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow();
    votes == null ? post.getVotes():votes;
    post.setVotes(votes+1);
    quoteRepository.save(post);
    return "redirect:/profile";

}
```